# Функция и указатель на неё

Tags: c++

Насколько я знаю для функций в `с++` (в силу исторических причин) верно следующее тождество:

```
foo == &foo;
```

Тобишь указатель на функцию это тоже что и функция и наоборот. Однако, типы у этих значений разные:

```cpp
std::is_same<decltype(foo), decltype(&foo)>::value == false;
```

Почему типы разные? И какие они?

Comment: Не думаю что это тождество верно для С++, может для С да..., потому что для &foo идет речь об указателе на объект по адресу, а foo это само объявление.

Comment: @ИндиПутный я так понимаю вы о первом тождестве - он действительно равно. Это может показаться странным и не понятным, но дело в том, что на заре становления `C` две лаборатории (понмю что одна Беркли, а вторую не помню) использовали разный синтаксис для создания переменных указывающих на функции. Когда дошло дело до стандартизации, то пришлось оставить оба варианта, иначе код одной из лабораторий оказался бы не валидным

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Типы у функции и указателя на функцию действительно совершенно разные. Однако поведение значений типа "функция" в выражениях в С и С++ во многом аналогично поведению значений типа "массив": во многих контекстах в выражениях значение типа "функция" само по себе, безо всякого участия с вашей стороны неявно преобразуется ("decays")  к значению типа "указатель на функцию".

Ваш пример с оператором `==` - как раз пример такого контекста. Формально слева у вас стоит функция, а справа - указатель на функцию, который вы получили при помощи оператора `&`. Но фактически до оператора `==` левый операнд "доходит" уже преобразованным к типу "указатель на функцию". Этот указатель "получился сам", как результат вышеупомянутого неявного преобразования.

Соверешенно аналогичным образом для массива `int a[10]` выполняется равенство

```
&a[0] == a
```

несмотря на то, что исходные типы в левой и правой части этого равенства совершенно разные.

Для случая функции будут выполняться также и равенства

```
*foo == &foo
***foo == ***&***&**foo;
```

и т.п.

В таких контекстах, как унарный оператор `&`, оператор `sizeof`, спецификатор `decltype` и др., неявного преобразования не происходит. Поэтому в этих контекстах вы видите истинный, непреобразованный тип функции. (То же самое справедливо и для массивов).

---

Вышесказанное относится к поведению *значений* типа "функция" в выражениях. Поведение самого типа "функция" в объявлениях - совсем другая, отдельная история. В объявлениях тип "функция" почти всегда остается типом "функция".

Например, объявление

```
decltype(foo) a = foo;
```

является некорректным. `decltype(foo)` видит тип "функция", в результате чего идентификатор `a` объявляется с типом "функция". Функцию невозможно "инициализировать".

В то же время, согласно правилам поведения `decltype`, вот такое объявление

```
decltype((foo)) b = foo;
```

является совершенно корректным - оно объявляет `b` как переменную-указатель на функцию. Благодаря "лишним" скобкам внутри `decltype`, значение типа "функция" успевает неявно преобразоваться к значению типа "указатель" и `decltype` видит уже не тип "функция", а тип "указатель на функцию".

Comment: В таком случае мне тогда не совсем понятно поведение почему подобная строка отказывается компилироваться: `std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(foo)>sp{&number, foo};` где `void foo(int *){}`. При этом когда я указываю `decltype(&foo)` то этот код компилируется. Что-то не сходится ...

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch: А при чем здесь это вообще? Почему вы решили, что это вообще может работать? У `std::unique_ptr` нет такого конструктора.

Comment: Но мне как-раз таки и не понятно, почему код вроде `decltype(foo) a = foo;` не будет собираться. А вот такой: `template <typename T>
auto tmp(T a) -> decltype(a) {
  return a;
} /*some other code*/ auto a = tmp<decltype(foo)>(foo);` - собереться

Comment: Не нужно переусердствовать с  decltype.  Это то же самое, что и написать  auto a = tmp(foo);  Тип выедится из аргумента шаблона. Это то же самое что написать auto a = foo; auto b == a; Почему это не должно работать?...

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch: Объявления параметров функций - это как раз тот редкий  контекст, где тип "функция" в объявлении трансформируется в тип "указатель на функцию". Поэтому ваша функция `tmp` ожидает указатель в качестве аргумента и ваш код компилируется.